# How can I dynamically set the dimensions of a html lock screen to the dimensions of a rotating iPad?

Tags: css, ipad, orientation, lockscreen

So I'm making a lock screen with HTML, and I'd like to make the text centered on the iPad in portrait and landscape.
 The only way I can center it either way is by using `width: 1024px; height: 768px;` or `width: 768px; height: 1024px;` depending on the orientation.

I tried:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  body {
    width: 768px;
    height: 1024px;
  }
} 

@media only screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  body {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
  }
}
```

but to no avail. I was thinking I may need js.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try `width: 100%`, and for the height:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('#element').css('height', windowHeight);
```